# Inconsistent MEDIA URLs in Django 3.0 vs 3.1 in tests

Tags: django

I have a Django project whose models have a thumbnail image, and I have some tests to check the generated paths of the images.

```py
# myapp/models.py
from django.db import models

def thumbnail_upload_path(instance, filename):
    # There's more happening in this method, but to simplify:
    return f"books/{filename}"

class Book(models.Model):
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=thumbnail_upload_path, null=False, blank=True, default=""
    )
```

```py
# tests/myapp/test_models.py
from django.test import TestCase
from myapp.factories import BookFactory  # using factoryboy

class BookTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_thumbnail_url(self):
        book = BookFactory(thumbnail__filename="tester.jpg")
        self.assertTrue(book.thumbnail.url.startswith("books/tester"))
```

That test passes in Django 2.2 and 3.0.

But when running it in Django 3.1 the thumbnail URL starts with a slash: "/books/tester..."

I'm *guessing* it's [this change in 3.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/#id1)...

> The `STATIC_URL` and `MEDIA_URL` settings set to relative paths are now prefixed by the server-provided value of `SCRIPT_NAME` (or `/` if not set). This change should not affect settings set to valid URLs or absolute paths.

I'm not sure how to make the test behaviour consistent in all Django versions.

When running the tests I set `MEDIA_ROOT` to `tempfile.mkdtemp()`.

I've tried appending a `"/"` to the end of that. I've tried setting `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` to `"/"`.

On the actual website - not in the tests - I have `MEDIA_ROOT = "/"` and the image paths are fine (starting with a forward slash) in all those versions of Django.

How do I make the tests pass in all versions of Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this was that in the settings used for my tests I hadn't set `MEDIA_URL`. If I explicitly set it to `MEDIA_URL = "/media/"` then the thumbnail URL stars with `/media/books/tester...` in both Django 3.0 and 3.1.

The reason for this is alluded to (although not made explicit) [in the `MEDIA_URL` docs for 3.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_URL), which is similar to the change note I quoted in the question:

> If `MEDIA_URL` is a relative path, then it will be prefixed by the server-provided value of `SCRIPT_NAME` (or `/` if not set). This makes it easier to serve a Django application in a subpath without adding an extra configuration to the settings.

This *doesn't* explicitly say this, which appears to be true:

> If you do not set `MEDIA_URL`, and `SCRIPT_NAME` is not set, then `settings.MEDIA_URL` will be `""` (an empty string) in Django 3.0, but `"/"` in Django 3.1

I *guess* `SCRIPT_NAME` isn't set when running the tests.